# Why the type inference algorithm tries to find the most specific type?

Tags: java, generics

From [Oracle's documentation of **Type Inference**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)

> Type inference is a Java compiler's ability to look at each method
>   invocation and corresponding declaration to determine the type
>   argument (or arguments) that make the invocation applicable. The
>   inference algorithm determines the types of the arguments and, if
>   available, the type that the result is being assigned, or returned.
>   Finally, the inference algorithm tries to find the most specific type
>   that works with all of the arguments.
>
> To illustrate this last point, in the following example, inference
>   determines that the second argument being passed to the pick method is
>   of type Serializable:

```
static <T> T pick(T a1, T a2) { return a2; }
Serializable s = pick("d", new ArrayList<String>());
```

Why the algorithm tries to find the most specific type  ?

Comment: Why shouldn't it?

Comment: @defaultlocale one way of answering this question is to answer why shouldn't it ? if u know why shouldn't it please answer and I will accept it gleefully.

Comment: because there would be no such thing as method overloading if it didnt

Comment: @Geek I'm not sure I understood your question. What are the alternatives? Taking the most general type will always result in `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: If it should not pick the most specific type, what does it should pick? Assume there are two _not-so-specific_ types. Of the two which should it pick? You expect fallback mechanism only if you do not find specific types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because assignment compatibility would make the invocation ambiguous if this rule were not enforced.

For instance, [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) defines `print(Object)` and `print(String)` if the rule of the most specific type were not enforced, `print("bar")` could invoke `print(Object)` instead of print(`String`), which would be counterintuitive.

Note that type selection is based on compile-time types, so in the following example `print(Object)` is invoked:

```
PrintStream out = ...;
Object bar = "bar";
out.print(bar);
out.print((Object)"foo");
```